# Weird Behaviour on ActionFunction

Tags: actionfunction

today , i noticed a very weird behaviour on actionfunction's on complete action.

When i use action function like below function works as expected :

MY VF :

```
<!--Attention : rerender attribute did not used-->
<actionfunction name="test" oncomplete="callBack('{!result}')" action="{!myServerAction}"/>
<script>
function callBack(str){
console.log(str);
}
</script>
```

MY Server Side Method:

```
public string result{get;set;}
public void  myServerAction(){
this.result = "Success";
}
```

Console log:

```
"Success"
```

But when i use oncomplete like below , i got blank string on output :

MY VF:

```
<!--Attention : rerender attribute did not used-->
<button onclick="test();">TEST BUTTON</button>
<actionfunction name="test" oncomplete="callBack()" action="{!myServerAction}"/>
<script>
 function callBack(){
            console.log('{!result}');
            }
</script>
```

Console Log :
""

Does anyone have idea that how the first scenario works as expected without rerender attribute ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. In first method you are passing updated value as parameter thats why you are getting Success there.
And in the `Oncomplete` of `actionfunction` you are getting updated value there. Because `Actionfunction` is a VF component so when it perform action then salesforce refersh all the `getter setter` which also refresh the value of `result` and you get updated value.

In second approach you are not `rerendering` the section thats why you are not getting any value. `rerender` the section.

Comment: With your approach , we should see the updated result value in source html. (right click > inspect) but it is blank. So you may be wrong.

Comment: @erkançipil try to close inspect element and then open it again . Now check.